# Why do bitmap images not divisible by four and larger than 32 pixels in width cause erroneous line scanning when creating an array of the pixel data?

Tags: c++, bitmap, stdio, bitmapimage

I found a tutorial by Alejandro Rodriguez about how to create a simple bitmap reader.  It uses fseek and fread to read through the header sections of a 24bit bitmap, find the pertinent information such as width, height, and dataoffset, and scan the data section of a bitmap.  https://elcharolin.wordpress.com/2018/11/28/read-and-write-bmp-files-in-c-c/

It works, and it's lightweight, but begins to fail when bitmap image sizes exceed 32 pixels && contain more than 1 row && the width is not divisible by 4.  Bitmaps are padded to be divisible to 4 bytes for storage efficiency.  When the width is divisible by four the problem does not exist, however...  If I give the function a bitmap that contains for example an image of 42 pixels in width, and 2 pixels in height, the first scan line reads correctly, but sequential rows begin to pick up unwanted garbage padding that should be skipped.

An image of 42 pixels would have 2 pixels worth of padding at the end of each row.  This function works with 24-bit depth pixels, meaning 3 bytes per pixel, 6 bytes total padding for this example case.

The information parsed from the headers of the imageFile seems to be consistently correct.  I've double-checked that the calculated value of paddedRowSize is correct, and it always shows the correct theoretically calculated value.  I've been chewing on this problem for a couple of weeks now, and can't figure it out.  I'm hoping someone could shed some insight into what's going wrong...

In the for loop that iterates through the file using fseek and fread to scan the data section of the imageFile, there must be an issue causing some of the padded bytes to be picked up when being read into the currentRowPointer.  Why is this happening?  Please shed your sagely wisdom.

Here is the function in question, along with particulars:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
#define DATA_OFFSET_OFFSET 0x000A
#define WIDTH_OFFSET 0x0012
#define HEIGHT_OFFSET 0x0016
#define BITS_PER_PIXEL_OFFSET 0x001C
 
typedef unsigned int int32;
typedef short int16;
typedef unsigned char byte;
 
void ReadImage(const char *fileName,byte **pixels, int32 *width, int32 *height, int32 *bytesPerPixel)
{
        FILE *imageFile = fopen(fileName, "rb");
        int32 dataOffset;
        fseek(imageFile, DATA_OFFSET_OFFSET, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&dataOffset, 4, 1, imageFile);
        fseek(imageFile, WIDTH_OFFSET, SEEK_SET);
        fread(width, 4, 1, imageFile);
        fseek(imageFile, HEIGHT_OFFSET, SEEK_SET);
        fread(height, 4, 1, imageFile);
        int16 bitsPerPixel;
        fseek(imageFile, BITS_PER_PIXEL_OFFSET, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&bitsPerPixel, 2, 1, imageFile);
        *bytesPerPixel = ((int32)bitsPerPixel) / 8;
 
        
        // This is the line of line of code causing my issuesint paddedRowSize = 
        //4 * (((*width) + 3) / 4) * (*bytesPerPixel);
        //Correct line of code that makes it all work:
        int paddedRowSize = (((*width) * (*bytesPerPixel) + 3) / 4) * 4;
        int unpaddedRowSize = (*width)*(*bytesPerPixel);
        int totalSize = unpaddedRowSize*(*height);
        *pixels = (byte*)malloc(totalSize);
        int i = 0;
        byte *currentRowPointer = *pixels+((*height-1)*unpaddedRowSize);
        for (i = 0; i < *height; i++)
        {
                fseek(imageFile, dataOffset+(i*paddedRowSize), SEEK_SET);
            fread(currentRowPointer, 1, unpaddedRowSize, imageFile);
            currentRowPointer -= unpaddedRowSize;
        }
 
        fclose(imageFile);
}

int main() {

  uint32_t width;
  uint32_t height;
  uint32_t bytesPerPixel;
  byte *pixels;

  ReadImage("please_work.bmp", &pixels, &width, &height, &bytesPerPixel);
}
```

Comment: How do you check your resulting bitmap?

Comment: I've been using a for loop in main(): for (int i = 0; i < height * width * bytesPerPixel; ++i) {
    std::cout << int(pixels[i]) << " ";
  }

Comment: `(int)(4 * ceil((float)(*width) / 4.0f))*(*bytesPerPixel);` try to avoid unnecessary convertions to float. Here, much simpler way would be:
`4 * ((*width) + 3) / 4) * (*bytesPerPixel);`

Comment: Nice!  I'll test this out more

Comment: I missed one opening parenthesis there, sorry about that. It most likely won't solve your issue, though.

Comment: Ah, no worries.  I caught that, but definitely an improvement over the way I was doing it before.  Sadly, no, it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: You might add your input data (hex dump of a small file), your output data and expected output. That would be clearer than your description of the problem.

Comment: I figured it out!  After days of banging my head against the problem, and likely due to Kaznov's suggestion about simplifying the way paddedRowSize is calculated, I discovered that the way in which the rows are padded is bit-wise, and not pixel-wise.  Before paddedRowSize was being calculated by rounding the PIXELS to the next number divisible by four, which meant too many padded bytes were included into the calculated value.  The solution was to round the number of bytes to the next integer divisible by four.

Comment: Please do not modify your code after comments were given. Especially if that change is supposed to fix the issue. That makes all comments void and the question will never be useful for anyone looking for a similar problem.

Comment: I left the error included,  but commented it out next to the correction that makes the program work. The integrity of the issue is preserved.  Don't worry.